# Apache problems after upgrade from 12.10 to 13.10/14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade, apache2

I just finished upgrading my server to Ubuntu 14.04.2. Previously I had had it configured thanks to the "Perfect server" guide for 12.10.

Unfortunately, after the upgrade I cannot access any of the websites that had previously been working all right. The server was using ISPConfig, so after upgrading to 14.04, I did a manual update, reconfigured permissions and services, but got the following error

```
* Restarting web server apache2
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/000-ispconfig.local.conf:62
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8081
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

whereas the apache error.log lists the following:

```
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.301329 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3215] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.319274 2015] [:notice] [pid 3220] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 3220)
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.586557 2015] [:notice] [pid 3215] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.586612 2015] [:notice] [pid 3215] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.687388 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3215] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.6 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 12 10:18:10.687465 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3215] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Mar 12 10:21:31.520361 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3215] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Could you, please, help me figure a way out of this mess?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is apparently running already on ports you're trying to bind to.
What is it? You'll have to find out yourself, I'm afraid.
What may help you with that is anyway netstat command. Try netstat -nap | grep 8080 (or 8081) to find out which process is using this port.